# Put a link on an Image Sprite

Tags: html, css

I'm having a difficulty linking image sprites. I want them to lead to particular websites but when I click the image sprite, it doesn't work at all. Are all image sprites like this? Could there be an alternative solution? [image]

```
<div class="footer1">
     <div class="fb"><a href="#"></a></div>
     <div class="ig"><a href="#"></a></div>
     <div class="yt"><a href="#"></a></div>
     <div class="twt"><a href="#"></a></div>
     <div class="pin"><a href="#"></a></div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fb {
  background: url('../images/sites.png') no-repeat -79px -109px;
  width: 302px;
  height: 302px;
}

.ig {
  background: url('../images/sites.png') no-repeat -459px -110px;
  width: 307px;
  height: 307px;
}

.yt {
  background: url('../images/sites.png') no-repeat -852px -115px;
  width: 299px;
  height: 299px;
}

.twt {
  background: url('../images/sites.png') no-repeat -1244px -114px;
  width: 295px;
  height: 293px;
}

.pin {
  background: url('../images/sites.png') no-repeat -1632px -112px;
  width: 293px;
  height: 293px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the div within a hyperlink

```
<div class="footer1">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="fb">
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="ig">
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="yt">
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="twt">
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="pin">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="fb"><a href="**Enter specific Link Here**"></a></div>
```

**you need to give specific links in href attribute like [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com)**

Comment: Yes it still doesnt work im sorry

Answer (score 0):

Paste your Links in href=""
Example

`<a href="https://facebook.com/user...."><div class="fb"></div></a>`
And Place img `<div>` tag inner `<a>` tag For you click the div it redirect

Get your Links in
Corresponding social media
*https://www.facebook.com/username*